What's the image it all started with?
Below is a small sequence, showing every element, except the first. What is the image it all started with?

text version:

, ,r,r,r, , , ,g,g,g, , ,r, , , ,r, ,g,r,r,r,g, , ,g,g,g, , ,r, , , ,r, ,g,r,r, ,g, , ,g,g, ,r, , , , , , , ,r, , , , , ,g,r,r,r,g, , , , , , , , ,g,g,g, , ,r, , , ,r, ,g,r,r,r,g, , ,g,g,g, , , ,r,r,r, , , , , , , , , ,g,g,g,r, ,r, , , ,g, , , , , ,r, ,g,r,r,r,g, , ,g,g,g, , , , , , ,r, , , , , ,g, , ,r,r,r, , , ,g,g,g, , , ,r,r,r,r, ,r,g,g,g, , ,g, , , ,g, , ,r,r,r, , , ,g,g,g,r, ,r, , , , , , , , , ,
,g, ,r, ,g, , , , , ,r, , , , , ,g, , , , , , , ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, , , ,g, ,r, , , ,r, ,g, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,g, , , , , ,r, , ,r, , , , , ,g, ,r,g, ,g,r, , ,r, ,r,g, ,g, , , , , , ,g, ,g, , , ,r, ,r, , , , , , ,r, , , , , ,g, , , , , , , , , , , ,r, , , , , ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, , , , , ,r, , , , , , , , , , , ,g, ,r, , ,g,r, ,g, , ,r,g, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,r
,g,g, ,g,g, , , , ,r,r, , ,r,r, ,g, , , , , , , ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, , , , ,g, , , , , , ,g,g, , , , , , , , , ,r,r,r,g, , , ,g, , , , , , , , , , ,g, , ,r, , ,r,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, , , ,r, ,g, ,g, , , , , , , ,g, , , , ,g, ,g,r, ,r, , , , , ,g,r,r,r,g, , , , , , , , ,g,g, ,r, , , , ,g, , ,r,r, ,r, , ,g,g, ,g,g, , , , ,r,r, , ,r,r, , , , ,g,g,g,g, ,r,r, ,r,r, , ,g, ,g,g, ,g,r,r,r, , , , , , , , , , , ,g,
,g, ,r, ,g, , , , , ,r, , , , ,g,g, , , , ,r, , ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, , , ,g, ,r, , , ,r, ,g, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,g, , , , , ,r,g, , , , , ,r,r, , , , , ,g, ,r,g, ,g,r, ,g,r, ,r,g, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,r, ,r, , , ,g, ,g, , , , , ,r,g, ,g,r, ,g,r, ,r, , , , , , ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, , , , , ,r, , , , , , , , , , , ,g, ,r,g, , ,r, , ,r, , ,g, ,g, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ,
,g, ,r, ,g, , ,g,g,g, , ,r, , , , , , , , , ,r, ,g, , , ,g, ,r, , , ,r, ,g,r,r, ,g, , ,g,g, ,r, , ,r,r,r,g, ,r,g,g,g,r, , , ,r, , , ,g,r, ,r,g, , , , , ,r, ,r,g,g,g, , ,g,r,r,r,g, ,r,g,g,g,r, , , , , , , ,g,r,r,r,g, , , , , ,r, , ,g,g,g, , ,r, , , , , , ,r, ,r, , ,g,g, ,g,g, , ,r,r,r, , ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, ,r, ,g, , ,g,g,g, , , , , , , , , ,r,r,r, , , ,g,g,g, , , , , , ,r, , , , , , , ,r, , , , , , , , , ,



It reminds me faintly of rot13(Pbajnl'f Tnzr bs Yvsr).

It might be rot13(n pryyhyne nhgbzngba), yeah.

The sequence starts with:

 

The sequence ...

 ... consists of 35 blocks of 5×5 pixels each. Each block represents two capital letters in a 5×5 "font", a red one and a green one. The letters are overlaid in an exclusive-or fashion: If a pixel is used by none of the letters or by both letters, it is blank. Otherwise, it is either red or green.

 The first given symbol are a T and an H. In the middle of the sequence, there is a combination of X and O. The missing symbol at the beginning is a T  and a G.

The whole sequence ...

 ... is a well-known sentence without spaces or punctuation. The red sentece is shifted one letter to the right, so that the first symbol is the last and first letters of the sentence combined.

 The sentence is the pangram:




It's funny, your answer is correct, but I had a completely different reasoning in mind.
V unq va zvaq gung rirel yrggre vf gur zhgngvba bs gur cerivbhf yrggre: Gur erq qbgf unir gb or erzbirq, gur terra qbgf unir gb or nqqrq. Fb sbe gur vavgvny yrggre V unq whfg n oynpx 'G' va zvaq. Vg rkcynvaf gur erq/terra pbybef nf jryy. Ohg lbhe rkcynangvba vf inyvq nf jryy :)

Hehe. I thought about the alternative rendering of he first symbol, but rot13(gbbx vg nf n dhrfgvba jurgure gur fragrapr jbhyq jenc be abg. Guvaxvat bs gurz nf bireynvq yrggref urycrq zr jvgu gur yrggref gung qba'g unir n fgenvtugsberjjneq sbez (W, X, L, ...). Naljnl, lbh pna vzntvar gur erq yrggref nf "pneel" sebz gur ynfg fgrc. sebz juvpu gb perngr gur arj barf. V qvqa'g frr gur fvtavsvpnapr bs erq naq terra, ohg hfrq k naq b va zl jbexfurrg, juvpu xvaqn jbexf sbe qryrgr naq vafreg, gbb.)

Anyhow, I think you deserve the green checkmark.
